# How to remove row with record count 0 from one particular report block in a joined report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports, report-builder

[image]I have a joined report on Account and its 2 related objects.

```
Report Block 1 with Account + OBJ1 

Report Block 2 with Account + OBJ2
```

**Joining** is on `Account Id`.

Both of these blocks have their own filters.

**Now I want to show only those records from (Account + OBJ2 report) that has atleast one record in (Account + OBJ1 report). That means, I want to remove entries with record count 0 from Report Block 1**

Please help me how to achieve the same.

Thanks.

Comment: can you put a RSF field that counts the details on the parent Account (or if not RSF, use DLRS)? Then you can filter out Accounts with 0 children

Comment: thanks cropredy !.. it is working using RSF...but can you please suggest if this is possible to create a formula field to get the roll-up summary within the report itself ? I think as we need to filter out records based on the value of roll up summary field we need to create it in the object definition itself.

Comment: Are you talking about report custom summary formula fields: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=building_custom_summary_formulas.htm&language=en_US ? These only work on summary and matrix reports